# How to make Firebug reload scripts?

Tags: firebug

When I make changes to any of my scripts and clear the cache, quite often I notice that Firebug still has the old copy of the script(s). How do I tell Firebug to reload the scripts so that it has the most recent copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebug reloads the scripts as soon as you reload the page. You may want to reload the page circumventing the cache by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or clear the cache before reloading it.

If it still doesn't work for you, ensure you have the latest version of Firebug installed (currently 2.0.6). If you have the latest version installed, it's probably a bug. In that case you should follow the [steps on the first aid page](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/I_found_a_Firebug_Bug!#To_understand_the_problem_so_it_can_be_fixed) for Firebug and [file an issue](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/entry) if it's really related to Firebug.

Comment: As I said, I cleared the cache, but that still didn't clear the old copies of the scripts in Firebug. Nor did the scripts reload with the page. (I have 2.0.6 installed.) [Ctrl}+[F5] worked, though (which I actually found out on my own).